# delete element from array without empty slots

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create an array like this and remove one element:

```
var test = []

test.push({
    bezeichnung: "test_1"
});
test.push({
    bezeichnung: "test_2"
});
test.push({
    bezeichnung: "test_3"
});

delete test[1]
```

But console.log(test.length) will show me "3", because my array shows an "empty slot" which will also count.

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice (`test.splice(1, 1)`)

Comment: yes, but splice will reindex the array. that shall not happen

Comment: Then it's not clear what you are asking. You complain about reindexing not happening (empty slot, length staying 3) but then you say you don't even want reindexing. If you want an empty slot instead of reindexing then what is the problem you have exactly? You seem to contradict yourself here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.splice()` to delete the data like this:

```
test.splice(1,1);
```

Then the `test.length` with show 2 as the array length.

If you do not wish to reindex the array, you can simply use the `.filter()` method to filter the `undefined` data from your array like this:

```js
var test = []

test.push({
    bezeichnung: "test_1"
});
test.push({
    bezeichnung: "test_2"
});
test.push({
    bezeichnung: "test_3"
});

delete test[1];

console.log(test.length) //will log 3
console.log(test.filter(a=>a).length) //will log 2
```

The last console statement in the above code snippet would filter the empty/undefined values from the array and show you the count.

Comment: but after this "test 3" is only accessible by test[1]. but it should be accessible with test[2] like before deletion

Comment: @Ghost108 "test 3" will still be accessible by test[2] when you will access it without using `filter()` method, as the method does not modify the actual array, it just returns a filtered array. As you can see in the below JS fiddle, they final log statement will have the array before deletion even after using filter:
https://jsfiddle.net/pastern/z9m0q7s5/3/

Comment: you are right! hmmm, maybe this could help me - I will try it! Thanks a lot :)